# Mac OS X 10.6.2 Install DBD::mysql

Tags: macos, mysql, perl

I've got a Mac Mini Server with Snow Leopard 10.6.2 64bit. I'm trying to install the Perl module DBD::mysql but cannot get it to work.

Is probably worth mentioning that this is the first time I'm using a Mac.

I got the following installed:

MySQL:
Community Server 5.1.42 x86 64bit (installed from the DMG Archive for Mac OS X 10.6 on MySQL's website)

Perl:
5.10.0 (pretty sure it's 64bit after looking through perl -V)

I'm trying to install DBD::mysql through the cpan console by typing:

```
sudo cpan
```

Then:

```
install DBD::mysql
```

This looks like it works until it gets to the make stage where it fails miserably.

I've put the output on pastebin. There are so many errors and I have no idea what they mean.

http://pastebin.com/f45ccc16f

I've got the MySQL server that comes with Mac OS X Server shut off. I tried installing the perl module on this mysql server as well but got the same result.

Hopefully someone here can help and let me know hat I'm doing wrong.

Thanks
Johannes

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098391/cpan-install-module-dbdmysql-fails-snow-leopard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the MySQL client libraries (and headers) installed. There probably will be some Mac MySQL client 'developer' package, so you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Worked fine after I installed the client libraries from here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/darwinsource/other/MySQL-49.binaries.tar.gz